# How to delete malformed remote branches/tags in git?

Tags: git

I don't know how it happened but somehow our remote repo has branches and tags named like this showing up when I run the `git ls-remote` command:

```
refs/heads/abc^{}
refs/tags/def^{}
```

And I cannot seem to delete them the usual way:

```
git push origin :refs/heads/abc^{} 
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in :refs/heads/abc^{}
```

How can I delete these malformed remote branches?

Comment: What repository are you using?  In GitHub it would be trivial to delete this branch on the remote (and likely on BitBucket as well).

Comment: @Tim Gitlab.  I don't see an interface for doing it there.

Comment: Have you tried simply `git push origin :abc^{}`? Which service are you using?

Comment: @isherwood Yes I tried the abbreviated push as well.  Not sure what you mean by service?  I'm using Gitlab.

Comment: @VonC Have you seen this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a branch, it's the result of a bad branch:

```
server$ echo echo 2e79bc84c11eda5d73add5a9dfc6bf03c50c432d > refs/heads/oogly
```

In this case, the SHA-1 I selected was that of an annotated tag.  You can't get "git branch" or "git checkout" to point to the tag, they always peel to the commit, but you can get a non-git-aware tool (like `echo` in this case) to make the broken branch.

Then, on client:

```
client$ git ls-remote
[snip]
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f    refs/heads/master
2e79bc84c11eda5d73add5a9dfc6bf03c50c432d    refs/heads/oogly
676699a0e0cdfd97521f3524c763222f1c30a094    refs/heads/oogly^{}
[snip]
```

Deleting the actual branch (`oogly` in this case, `abc` in yours) on the server will make the "peeled tag" go away on the client as well.  Note that if you want to save the tag, you should point a tag at it, if there isn't one already.

How this got created on the server in the first place, I have no idea.

Note that this is entirely normal for (annotated) tags: the server delivers both the tag and its SHA-1, and the SHA-1 of the underlying object to which it points.  The syntax is documented in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

> ```
>    <rev>^{}, e.g. v0.99.8^{}
>        A suffix ^ followed by an empty brace pair means the object could
>        be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until a non-tag
>        object is found.
> ```

Comment: Interesting!  Your technique worked... I made a temporary tag to save the location, then deleted the underlying refs/heads/abc branch, which as you posited had a 1:1 correlation with the bad branches/tags, then finally just recreated the tag/branch.  It worked!

Comment: Sorry I have to backtrack a little: 1) some of these malformed branches were already in fact tags, and 2) deleting the underlying tag solves the issue, but then pushing up a newly created replacement tag creates the issue again!